# "chkconfig --add rsync" と実行すると「サービス rsyncd は、chkconfig をサポートしていません。」とエラーになる

Tags: centos, vagrant, rsync

ネットワーク/サーバー構築初学者です。
おかしなことも書いてしまってるかもしれませんがよろしく願いします。

Windows7にて vagrant 1.7.2とvirtualbox4.3.26 の組み合わせで、仮想のプライベートネットワークを作成し、複数のゲストマシンを起動させています。ゲストOSは全てCentOS 6.6です。

この環境で今、puppetを使う練習をしています。
初心者なのでpuppet master や agent は使わず(≒使えず)、puppet apply コマンドのみを使いスタンドアローン実行ばかり試しているところです。
１台のマシンでの動作は大体できるようになってきたので、これの応用として、複数のマニフェストを作成し、それをネットワークの各ホストから取得させた後、それぞれにpuppet apply を実行させる試みをしようと思いました。
（後々、vagrant のプロヴィジョニングにも応用できるであろうという狙いです)

そこでファイルの配布ツールにはrsyncを選びました。
ソースからmakeして最新バージョン3.1.1をゲストマシン全機にインストールした後、マニフェストファイルを一括管理しているサーバーでrsyncをデーモン起動させる手順(rsync --daemonの実行)までは動作確認できました。

さらにもう一歩踏み込んで、rsync をpostfix等のデーモンと同じようにservice コマンドで起動・停止させたいと思ってます。

なのでまずは

```
chkconfig --add rsyncd
```

とコマンド実行したのですが、

```
サービス rsyncd は、chkconfig をサポートしていません。
```

というエラーが出てしまい、それ以降全く埒があきません。
これは一体どういうことなのでしょうか。
色々調べてみたのですがxinetdが関係しているらしい、等の情報は見つかれども、ps -aux で確認しても xinetd という名前は出てこないし、訳が分からないまま答えにまでたどり着けません。
このまま続けても答えが探せそうな気がしないので、これの理由を知ってる方がいらしたらどうかご教示お願いいたします。

以下はサービスとして起動するために書いた設定ファイルです。
他にも必要な情報があれば教えてください。

/etc/rsyncd.conf:

```
syslog facility = local5

use chroot = yes
uid = nobody
gid = nobody
max connections = 20
timeout = 600
read only = yes

[puppet]
    path = /vagrant/puppet
    host allow = <%= settings['host_allow'] %>
    refuse options = checksum
    dont compress = *
```

/etc/init.d/rsyncd:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

[ -f /usr/local/bin/rsync ] || exit 0

case "$1" in
  start)
    action "Starting rsyncd: " /usr/local/bin/rsync --daemon
    ;;
  stop)
    action "Stopping rsyncd: " killall rsync
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: rsyncd {start|stop}"
    exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

※ファイルの内容はこちらを参考にしました(SELinux云々のところは取り入れていません) -- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-JP/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-rsync-Configuration_Examples.html

ファイル名と権限:

```
$ ls -aFl /etc/init.d/rsyncd
-rwxrw-rw-. 1 root root 322  4月 30 22:00 2015 /etc/init.d/rsyncd*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/etc/init.d/rsyncdファイルにchkconfigの構成用のコメントが付いていないのが原因ではないでしょうか。
たとえば/etc/init.d/postfixには`# chkconfig: 2345 80 30`と書いた行があります。これ、シェルスクリプトの構文としてはコメントですが、chkconfigはここをみてどうやって登録するか決めます。
とりあえず動けばいいなら同じ内容を記述して`chkconfig --add rsyncd`すればたぶん動きます。
起動と停止の優先順位はそれなりに意味があるのですが、それはお使いのシステムの構成次第なので提示されている情報ではこれが最適というのは出せないです。が、postfixと同じでそれほど問題無いように思われます。

Answer (score 2):

rsyncd についてあまり情報が見つからず、また chkconfig の標準
サポートがなされていない原因は、ssh 経由で使うことがほとんど
だからではないでしょうか。

ssh を経由すれば通信路も暗号化されるし、認証も ssh に任せられます。
私も職場で rsync は普通に使っていますが、サービスとしては動かして
いません。

Comment: 確かに考えてみれば、デーモンにすること自体には、その必要がなかったです。

元々、この実験の応用後の青写真はvagrant でマルチホスト環境を作成する際の手間の軽減として、puppetのマニフェストを各ホストに配布し、それぞれのホストでpuppet apply を実行することでした。

そこでvagrant  up 実行後、先にpuppet マニフェストを持つサーバーを立ち上げておき(仮にマニフェストサーバーと名付けます)、その後起動するマシンがマニフェストサーバーからマニフェストを取得できれば良い。
と考えました。
ところが通常のrsync のようにsshを使うにはマシン間で鍵の情報をやり取りする必要があるため、仕方なく一段下がった認証方法で動ける、rsyncデーモンをマニフェストサーバーに立ち上げてしまおう(ftpはさすがに使わない)、が、通常のサービスのように動かせない、なぜ？という展開でした。

しかしデーモンにする価値があるのかと言われてみると、順序として、マニフェストサーバー用の公開鍵と秘密鍵をあらかじめ作成してホストOS側に用意しておき、各ホストの起動時に各々の共有フォルダへ秘密鍵をコピーするようVagrantfileに記述しておけば、プロヴィジョニングの段階ででマニフェストサーバーと個別にsshを通じたファイルの同期がとるシェルスクリプトを書けそうです。

Answer (score 1):

/etc/init.d/rsyncd については他の方がご指摘のとおり、"# chkconfig: ..." 行が無いためと思います。

rsync をソースからコンパイル、インストール済みのようですが、CentOS 6.x で提供されている rsync パッケージを利用する方法もあります。xinetd から起動する設定ファイル /etc/xinetd.d/rsync も含まれています。xinetd がインストールされていなければ、インストール、起動する必要があります。

```
# yum install rsync xinetd
# service xinetd start
# chkconfig rsync on
# ss -tln
  (TCP 873 番ポートが LISTEN していることを確認)
```

Comment: なるほど、それでググるとxinetd の話が出てきていたのですね。理解できました。

Answer (score 0):

横槍刺しますぶすり。

メンテナンスを考えてgitサーバーとかはいかがてしょうか。puppet applyのソースというならclone/pullあたりで取ればいいだけになります。

Comment: 確かに git という選択肢もありますね。